How to turn off keyboard led on Ubuntu 24.04?
On my Ubuntu 24.04 desktop, I work with keyboard in the dark and I hate keyboard leds, especially now that they are blinking for no reason.
The keyboard is a Strike Battle mechanical one, if that matters.
Appreciate your help on how to turn it off permanently.
